# How can my CNN produce an "unknown" label?

Tags: machine-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, image-recognition, supervised-learning

I have a dataset of 20k images of infected mango. I have built a web-based app using Flask, where a user can upload a picture, and my CNN model detects the disease. I have 6 classes in the model, which correspond to 6 types of diseases.

My question is: how do I train the model so that, if a user uploads any picture except infected mango, the model will show "not mango"?

Comment: Do you mean exactly "if an user uploads any picture except an infected mango" or "if an user uploads any picture except a mango"?

Comment: "any picture except a mango" @NikoNyrh

Comment: We had similar questions in the past. You can check them [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/18745/2444), [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/4889/2444), [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/26729/2444) and [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/26175/2444).